# Progress- percentage bar for webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a loading bar but with percentage. I mean imagine when it’s 50% it will show that number also it will fill until half. If it’s 75% it will go up until 3/4.

I am trying to do this with HTML,CSS and JS. So far I made up everything but at the same time number will increase (by clicking button) and pattern will fill up according to percentage? This part is challenging me. 
Can you lead me way if it’s possible? Or even if there is example so I can learn?

UPDATE CODE BELOW

```
    <script>
      var i = 0;

      function buttonClick5() {
        i += 5;
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = i + "€";

      }

      function percentage(per) {
        return (100 / 100) * per;
      }

    </script>
    <div class="textContainer">
    <p class="perc" id="here"></p>
    <script>
      document.getElementById('here').textContent = percentage(10) + "%";
    </script>
    <h2 id="demo">0€</h2>
  </div>
```

and css part

```
.textContainer {
margin-top:-10%;
margin-left: 30%;
height: auto;

  text-align: center;
}

.textContainer h2 {

margin-left: -40%;
  font-size: 500px;
  color: rgba(225, 225, 225, .1);
  background-image:  url(color3.jpg);
  background-repeat:repeat;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  animation: animateMid 15s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animateMid {
  0% {
    background-position: left 0px top 0px;
  }

  1% {
    background-position: left 1200px top 0px;
  }
}
```

basically with those I can just make pattern moving as background of the percentage but always at 100 per cent.

Comment: Is there any code you can share from what you tried so far?

Comment: I put the code!

Answer (score 0):

Use your percentage variable as a width of the div that shows progress. Add click even listener to your button that will update that percentage variable and width of the div. If you make a callback function that updates both at the same it would be easy for you. Share your code here so we can help further.

Comment: I am not fully adapted the frontend I am learning, is it possible to tell me through the code I made?